# Bokeh Components function, embed through an API

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, bokeh

Is it possible to build an API which can call bokeh's 'components' function to serve the  and  tags to be served at the front end ?

For ex the following code is  output of the components function:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.css" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var fn = function() {
      Bokeh.safely(function() {
        (function(root) {
          function embed_document(root) {

          var docs_json = '{"4679a6cd-12e0-4168-983e-135a2e29f86d":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"callback":null,"factors":["LP","KC","BDR","JHU","LKW","COL","GTK","POW","INM","PH","HO"]},"id":"f6f7ea91-f359-4edd-a3d0-4a78c8a5f049","type":"FactorRange"},{"attributes":{},"id":"b5b8c165-97b7-4186-968c-bb716863fcf0","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"ac5ff865-bb97-49c1-b48b-458af97677c3","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"43903bfe-e57a-4209-acff-69fb3ac987d7","type":"CategoricalTicker"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"f09064ff-2fbd-40ef-8655-7d15cc2c9078","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"be481d41-174d-44e9-aff0-bc542466e8b0","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"04a5ee34-c4b3-4091-b330-1b046c590def","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5521c46a-8d7e-4da4-bcd9-f4d2fce8fda4","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"8f60b37d-d8d0-4e4c-a697-7f82d69eb638","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"964bb707-8b12-46bc-bcad-92ab516a7a51","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"aeca19b9-3d69-4dfb-ba8a-9e4e25e6a9e6","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"3f8cfcd2-de17-4926-8cb1-5b0372efe0ca","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"7294de09-c621-411a-9e35-31f20b48165e","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"d2f923f0-030f-4e05-8f87-58e0e957f447","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"cabfb040-4b40-46c1-81d6-4d3bd56e7620","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"b31cafab-420a-43e4-a0ea-7d7ba424f5ba","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"84d31a0a-0596-47ea-ad1b-1ec36b760e90","type":"HelpTool"},{"id":"76f7b209-8983-43d8-a7f6-96d217013711","type":"HoverTool"}]},"id":"378f020f-33ce-4ae4-85fe-3e6bfc59a609","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"08fa23f5-ccdb-4811-aae3-7e7a3557999a","type":"CategoricalScale"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"cd1f4158-7918-4b54-8b4a-f1e152333437","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{},"id":"33e65275-4a69-48db-93f9-040cf94d504c","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"8441b708-7b9f-4a31-9487-d38bdc4c7300","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#6C69EB"},"height":{"value":0.5},"right":{"field":"Sales"},"y":{"field":"ID"}},"id":"ca5758ae-4572-48f3-be74-9e84322afbf2","type":"HBar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"b8eed6e8-eec8-497e-a2de-62e2e503bec9","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"841b8725-8df8-4673-8c4b-a08546f48c6d","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"beb6b439-f3a7-4a41-b107-7b7d36a4fc1e","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"ca5758ae-4572-48f3-be74-9e84322afbf2","type":"HBar"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"aa29be63-62fc-4116-b133-d905dee2bbdd","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"79f0f062-e8ae-44b8-b714-e3181a8763c1","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["Count","Sales","ID"],"data":{"Count":[177834,119206,107828,95426,75541,67647,61662,60852,32650,11511,3871],"ID":["LP","KC","BDR","JHU","LKW","COL","GTK","POW","INM","PH","HO"],"Sales":[314305933,185329243,188463555,150196418,134483188,102851629,127717657,126289415,51907783,24004317,32662]}},"id":"f09064ff-2fbd-40ef-8655-7d15cc2c9078","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"c1f39d73-fcf3-4288-bad1-3d5d51851031","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"b48ce5f5-e469-4147-9531-dc87bf04e2a0","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"6f1d229f-3088-44be-a746-cbfcc8fb8be1","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"f09064ff-2fbd-40ef-8655-7d15cc2c9078","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"e8d00a34-5945-48fa-9225-a6562477ad92","type":"HBar"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"be481d41-174d-44e9-aff0-bc542466e8b0","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"5e652ad2-126a-4eb2-ac84-902563c29a80","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"7294de09-c621-411a-9e35-31f20b48165e","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Merchant","axis_line_color":{"value":null},"formatter":{"id":"76cb3daf-61d3-4a12-a4a6-40f63758108e","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"8d2f49f8-19a4-4f2f-bd8e-d38ab5e07201","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"83a8c787-ec68-4496-ae53-67b03ba0e31a","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["Count","Sales","ID"],"data":{"Count":[177834,119206,107828,95426,75541,67647,61662,60852,32650,11511,3871],"ID":["LP","KC","BDR","JHU","LKW","COL","GTK","POW","INM","PH","HO"],"Sales":[314305933,185329243,188463555,150196418,134483188,102851629,127717657,126289415,51907783,24004317,32662]}},"id":"beb6b439-f3a7-4a41-b107-7b7d36a4fc1e","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"833dad25-6dc6-4e36-a9fa-578c58c2885d","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Sales","axis_line_color":{"value":null},"formatter":{"id":"08327f98-3e2c-4dc5-a337-6b45bb0026ba","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"major_label_text_font_size":{"value":"0pt"},"major_tick_line_color":{"value":null},"minor_tick_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"964bb707-8b12-46bc-bcad-92ab516a7a51","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"fbf71a90-71e2-4ee5-b53e-de0e5ff827fc","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"76cb3daf-61d3-4a12-a4a6-40f63758108e","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"9ba9f5f6-0a75-40cc-93ad-37ce28f66249","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"173a3635-c5d0-4c00-9f28-0fceac107750","type":"CategoricalAxis"}],"outline_line_alpha":{"value":0.2},"renderers":[{"id":"9ba9f5f6-0a75-40cc-93ad-37ce28f66249","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"3c705b55-1ccb-443a-8f0d-d64826834943","type":"Grid"},{"id":"173a3635-c5d0-4c00-9f28-0fceac107750","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"id":"c7f4a660-eeb6-4eb5-b196-8dbf00dadca4","type":"Grid"},{"id":"8f60b37d-d8d0-4e4c-a697-7f82d69eb638","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"79f0f062-e8ae-44b8-b714-e3181a8763c1","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"841b8725-8df8-4673-8c4b-a08546f48c6d","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"378f020f-33ce-4ae4-85fe-3e6bfc59a609","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"6f1d229f-3088-44be-a746-cbfcc8fb8be1","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"5521c46a-8d7e-4da4-bcd9-f4d2fce8fda4","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"eab96392-b6f3-485d-a66a-347971b60f7c","type":"FactorRange"},"y_scale":{"id":"08fa23f5-ccdb-4811-aae3-7e7a3557999a","type":"CategoricalScale"}},"id":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"tooltips":[["Merch_ID","@ID"],["Revenue","Rs @Sales{0,0.000}"],["Visits","@Count"]]},"id":"76f7b209-8983-43d8-a7f6-96d217013711","type":"HoverTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"8d2f49f8-19a4-4f2f-bd8e-d38ab5e07201","type":"CategoricalTicker"},{"attributes":{"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"423fd619-16aa-4c1c-92f2-3f43b0508b6e","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"3c705b55-1ccb-443a-8f0d-d64826834943","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#6C69EB"},"height":{"value":0.5},"right":{"field":"Sales"},"y":{"field":"ID"}},"id":"e8d00a34-5945-48fa-9225-a6562477ad92","type":"HBar"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"tooltips":[["Merch_ID","@ID"],["Revenue","Rs @Sales{0,0.000}"],["Visits","@Count"]]},"id":"de3b2f27-e37f-4b6a-82dd-21acf044db94","type":"HoverTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"423fd619-16aa-4c1c-92f2-3f43b0508b6e","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{},"id":"964bb707-8b12-46bc-bcad-92ab516a7a51","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"fbf71a90-71e2-4ee5-b53e-de0e5ff827fc","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"83a8c787-ec68-4496-ae53-67b03ba0e31a","type":"CategoricalAxis"}],"outline_line_alpha":{"value":0.2},"renderers":[{"id":"fbf71a90-71e2-4ee5-b53e-de0e5ff827fc","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"aeca19b9-3d69-4dfb-ba8a-9e4e25e6a9e6","type":"Grid"},{"id":"83a8c787-ec68-4496-ae53-67b03ba0e31a","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"id":"4d6774e0-3705-4789-a6ca-a7ac65568347","type":"Grid"},{"id":"c1f39d73-fcf3-4288-bad1-3d5d51851031","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"5e652ad2-126a-4eb2-ac84-902563c29a80","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"cd1f4158-7918-4b54-8b4a-f1e152333437","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"86cd5a01-af84-4b3b-8e6c-5b9ca89bf54e","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"ac5ff865-bb97-49c1-b48b-458af97677c3","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"8441b708-7b9f-4a31-9487-d38bdc4c7300","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"f6f7ea91-f359-4edd-a3d0-4a78c8a5f049","type":"FactorRange"},"y_scale":{"id":"78f4920d-12d8-4da5-b9a6-f7f7c6c60ad4","type":"CategoricalScale"}},"id":"b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{},"id":"78f4920d-12d8-4da5-b9a6-f7f7c6c60ad4","type":"CategoricalScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"8cb69d9c-a6f3-456e-ab3f-c66bc12d2753","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"beb6b439-f3a7-4a41-b107-7b7d36a4fc1e","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"aa29be63-62fc-4116-b133-d905dee2bbdd","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"b31cafab-420a-43e4-a0ea-7d7ba424f5ba","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"84d31a0a-0596-47ea-ad1b-1ec36b760e90","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"8f60b37d-d8d0-4e4c-a697-7f82d69eb638","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"d2f923f0-030f-4e05-8f87-58e0e957f447","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"08327f98-3e2c-4dc5-a337-6b45bb0026ba","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Sales","axis_line_color":{"value":null},"formatter":{"id":"8cb69d9c-a6f3-456e-ab3f-c66bc12d2753","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"major_label_text_font_size":{"value":"0pt"},"major_tick_line_color":{"value":null},"minor_tick_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"423fd619-16aa-4c1c-92f2-3f43b0508b6e","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"9ba9f5f6-0a75-40cc-93ad-37ce28f66249","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"43903bfe-e57a-4209-acff-69fb3ac987d7","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"c7f4a660-eeb6-4eb5-b196-8dbf00dadca4","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"3f8cfcd2-de17-4926-8cb1-5b0372efe0ca","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"grid_line_color":{"value":null},"plot":{"id":"b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"8d2f49f8-19a4-4f2f-bd8e-d38ab5e07201","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"4d6774e0-3705-4789-a6ca-a7ac65568347","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"c1f39d73-fcf3-4288-bad1-3d5d51851031","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"b7b5c738-7223-4d00-b1e5-6ed7356788c6","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"cabfb040-4b40-46c1-81d6-4d3bd56e7620","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Merchant","axis_line_color":{"value":null},"formatter":{"id":"b48ce5f5-e469-4147-9531-dc87bf04e2a0","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"43903bfe-e57a-4209-acff-69fb3ac987d7","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"173a3635-c5d0-4c00-9f28-0fceac107750","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"factors":["LP","KC","BDR","JHU","LKW","COL","GTK","POW","INM","PH","HO"]},"id":"eab96392-b6f3-485d-a66a-347971b60f7c","type":"FactorRange"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"b8eed6e8-eec8-497e-a2de-62e2e503bec9","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"b5b8c165-97b7-4186-968c-bb716863fcf0","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"b7b5c738-7223-4d00-b1e5-6ed7356788c6","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"04a5ee34-c4b3-4091-b330-1b046c590def","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"33e65275-4a69-48db-93f9-040cf94d504c","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"833dad25-6dc6-4e36-a9fa-578c58c2885d","type":"HelpTool"},{"id":"de3b2f27-e37f-4b6a-82dd-21acf044db94","type":"HoverTool"}]},"id":"86cd5a01-af84-4b3b-8e6c-5b9ca89bf54e","type":"Toolbar"}],"root_ids":["b8da88d1-af1a-412d-bf22-d9b50a23a43e","f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.12.13"}}';
          var render_items = [{"docid":"4679a6cd-12e0-4168-983e-135a2e29f86d","elementid":"db6af978-6cba-4467-89f0-3c71b45488d1","modelid":"f3c6ef5c-8fc8-423d-ae32-5bb031626309"}];
          root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

          }
          if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
            embed_document(root);
          } else {
            var attempts = 0;
            var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
              if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                embed_document(root);
                clearInterval(timer);
              }
              attempts++;
              if (attempts > 100) {
                console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                clearInterval(timer);
              }
            }, 10, root)
          }
        })(window);
      });
    };
    if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
    else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
  })();
</script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="bk-root">
    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="db6af978-6cba-4467-89f0-3c71b45488d1"></div>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Given that only the docs_json and render_items are the only changing values, would it be possible to pass them to front end using an API ?
Furthermore build the bokeh plots at the front end itself ?

Comment: It's all possible, given that that's exactly how `bokeh serve` works - it creates a server and feeds the document and all changes to it via a WS connection. For the front-end part, there's BokehJS.
Perhaps you could reformulate your question to specify what exact problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Im trying to send my bokeh plots to the front end which is angular 4 based website. The BokehJS doesn't seem to have much flexibility with how it plots compared to bokeh itself. Hence building an api to pass values from the components function to the front end, itself. Could you help using the bokeh.serve function to explain how it could work instead ?

Comment: Bokeh itself uses BokehJS, so BokehJS cannot be less flexible.
Bokeh already has an API to embed its plots in web pages. E.g. you can use `Bokeh.embed.add_model_from_session` to add any plot to any DOM element.

Comment: There isn't any documentation regarding the `add_model_from_session` method. Secondly i've tried earlier, but i can figure out a javascript callback for the same, so no way to update the front end chart if there is a change in input

Comment: Sadly, Bokeh doesn't have all of the relevant documentation, yes. But the source code is pretty easy to read in most of th cases.
Consider this example: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#single-module-format You can view it in a web page, and it will react to the input changes. You can embed it as an iframe within your Angular application. If so, you can directly embed it, without the iframe.
Yet another way to embed it is to use `server_document` (https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#bokeh-applications).

Comment: but then how could these be embedded onto a webpage, with filters functionalities ?

Comment: You should definitely provide some example so people have something to work with in order to answer your question. The example should as complete as possible, with only embedding missing, as that's what you're trying to implement.

Comment: Eugene, I have posted another question with more details(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959769/how-to-link-my-backend-bokeh-plots-to-an-angular-4-front-end-dynamically). See if this helps understanding the problem. I'll try availing the code as well.